# How do I link multiple lisp-fasl files into a single file?

Tags: compilation, load, common-lisp, sbcl

I started learning lisp and am looking for an efficient way to manage my personal libraries.

So i thought it would be useful to compile my library into a single fasl-file (containing both package-information and actual implementation), that i can afterwards load with `(load "lib.fasl")` to include the library. Problem is, the library consists of multiple **.lisp*-files, lets say *foo.lisp* and *bar.lisp*.

I came as far as to compile them separately using `(compile-file "foo.lisp")` and `(compile-file "bar.lisp")`, respectively.

Obviously it would be rather messy having to `LOAD` every file of the library (i.e. *foo.fasl* and *bar.fasl*) manually when i want to use them, so i am looking for something like

```
(link "foo.fasl" "bar.fasl" :output "lib.fasl")
```

or

```
(compile-file "foo.lisp" "bar.lisp" :output "lib.fasl")
```

to produce a single *lib.fasl*, which I can then `LOAD`.

I don't want to use core-files, because I want to be able to combine my libraries flexibly (which would require to create a separate core-file for every possible combination of libraries).

I searched both the SBCL user-manual for lisp-functions doing this and the SBCL manpage for functionality using the CLI, but I wasn't able to find anything.

I would prefer a solution using SBCL, but I will take anything else too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In ASDF I found a nice tool to manage libraries, but I think this question still interesting, because linking to fasls does not seem to be such a hard task and still there does not seem to be an obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`cat`](http://www.linfo.org/cat.html):

```
$ cat f1.fasl f2.fasl .... > mypackage.fasl
```

Note that the more common way is creating [images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480083/850781).

You might also want to explore [`asdf`](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think concatenating would do it. As I said above, images / core-files are seem fine for releasing software, but are a bit to static for the purpose of combining lots of different libraries. Already found ASDF!

Answer (score 4):

IIRC for SBCL you just concatenate the FASL files into one file.

ASDF 3 has a way to build a single FASL file out of a system or a system with all dependencies (see `compile-bundle-op` and `monolithic-compile-bundle-op`).

In its portable library `uiop` there is also a function `combine-fasls`, which supports multiple CL implementations.

Comment: At the moment i find plain ASDF (using `defsystem`, `:defsystem-depends-on` and `require`) sufficient. Is there any advance in using `monolithic-compile-bundle-op` to create a software-release in contradiction to `require`ing my system and creating an image?